# How to get api_token for Sportmonks?

Tags: python

I want to take informations from soccerApi and I do not really understand from where should i take it. https://github.com/Dmitrii-I/sportmonks

```
from sportmonks.soccer import SoccerApiV2
soccer = SoccerApiV2(api_token='My API token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register for an API Token and put it in place of `'My API token'`.

In order to get the API token, you would have to register for an account here: https://www.sportmonks.com/products/soccer

However, do not push your repo to github with the API token saved as other people can use your token. I would advise creating a separate file, for example `config.js` and then creating a variable with your token inside it. export the variable containing your token so that you can import it in inside the file that needs it.

Add `config.js` to .gitignore so that you do not push your API token to github.

However, if you are not publishing your work to github then you'd be fine just putting your token in place of `'My API token'`